# 'SelectElement' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments ToolsQA

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ToolsQA
{
    class FirstTestCase
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(" http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/");
            String st = "dld";
            SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(st);


            //oSelection.


        }
    }
}
```

Has an error, why? Becouse in http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/dropdown-multiple-select-operations-in-c/ everything is OKAY!

Comment: `st` doesn't seem to be web-element

Answer (score 0):

`new SelectElement()` takes the parameter of `webElement` type

You are passing `string` as parameter. change your parameter type and then try -

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.your_locator);
SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(element);
```

Comment: It does not matter, this error will be again in your variant also